# Change Javascript src Depending On PHP Output

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax, xml

How do you change the the Javascript src in foo.html in reaction to the output created from cond1.php via AJAX? For example, if cond1.php echoes 1 then `src="something.js"`.

I'd like to know this because in my actual project I will be using the Google Books API and I will need to use a different src depending on the output from the PHP file.

**foo.html**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>  
  <body>
 <!-- Input -->
    <div class="form">
      <form onsubmit="makeRequest(); return false">
        <input type="text" id="inputText" name="inputText">
        <input type="submit">
      </form>
    </div>
 
    <br>
    
    <!-- Output -->
    <div class="txtBox">
      <textarea  id="txtBox">
      </textarea>
    </div>
    
    <!-- AJAX to create output using cond1.php file-->
    <script>
        function makeRequest() {
            httpRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();            
            httpRequest.onreadystatechange = function() {               
                document.getElementById("txtBox").innerHTML = httpRequest.responseText;
            };
            httpRequest.open("POST", "cond1.php", true);
            httpRequest.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
            httpRequest.send("inputText=" + document.getElementById("inputText").value);
        }

    </script>
    <script src=""></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

**cond1.php**

```html
<?php
$input = $_POST["inputText"];

if ($input == "") {
    echo "0";
} else {
    echo "1";
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out jQuery's [getScript](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/ajax_getscript.asp) method, this will allow you to dynamically and conditionally load your JavaScript via ajax.

Answer (score 0):

You can dynamically create script tag in your DOM and set it's src with ajax response.

```
httpRequest.onreadystatechange = function() {               
  document.getElementById("txtBox").innerHTML = httpRequest.responseText;
  var scriptElem = document.createElement("script");
  scriptElem.src = httpRequest.responseText;
  document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(scriptElem)
};
```

Check if this works for you.

Comment: Hi Sandeeproop, I tried it out. Firstly I loaded the page and then checked the source. src="" as expected. I then typed in "asdf" into the input and pressed submit. After checking the source code for the second time I noticed that it is still src="". I'm guessing it was meant to show src="1". Did I do something wrong?

Comment: add console.log(httpRequest.responseText) in your code and  check what value u r getting.

Comment: I put in `console.log(httpRequest.responseText)` after `httpRequest = new XMLHttpRequest()`. I typed `asdf` and then submitted. The following is what is shown in the Javascript console for Chrome. First there was a blank line with `:foo.html:24` at the end. On the next line there was a red x followed by a triangle pointing right followed by the text `GET http://localhost/1`  and then `foo.html:30`.

Comment: This means that you are getting proper path and now you can inspect your html <head> tag and check the new script tag with src= "http://localhost/1" in it.

Comment: So, how do I check that the src has changed? Maybe it is working and I'm not looking at it the right way to notice.